# Referencing a type from a package library in Delphi

Tags: delphi, variables

I have inherited a legacy Delphi project for which I have to do a code modification. But to start with, I have problem compiling the project into a "correct" application. As I am not familiar with Delphi, I am not sure what is missing.

So far, the only changes I have done are around PATH for references and packages wherever I could find an absolute path that was different on my PC. It is compiling and running. However, one of the variable remains "incorrectly" initialized at run-time (value is nil). I am a bit surprised because I have not changed anything in the code, that is from an application otherwise running.

The type of this variable is defined in a package library (for which I have the code as well, that compiles, and that is in the list of "Packages" checked in the Project Options.

Some code sample:

```
Unit Unit3
interface
uses
  VCLZ;
TFrmCCB = class(TForm)
  vz: TVCLZ;


implementation

procedure TFrmCCB.FormCreate(Sender: TObject)
var
  [...]
begin
  vz.SetPath := 'C:\'; //at this point vz is nil
```

Do I have to add some code to get vz to not be nil, or does it look like a configuration problem with the definition not found at run time or something like that? I would seem strange that something is missing in the code though, as I have not done any change there yet and the program is otherwise running.

Comment: You have to initialize `vz` somehow. Only you can know how.

Comment: Isn't "vz: TVLZ;" already meant to create an object of this type ?

Comment: No. Only reserve memory. You are lucky that instance fields are initialized to zero, otherwise it would have been random. But all this  sheds some doubt that this code has run in this form.

Comment: Where do I find how to initialize this? What kind of call or function should I be looking for?

Comment: You aren't going to be successful working on a legacy project with no knowledge at all of the language. It is a big mistake to attempt what you are doing. You need to recognise what you know, and what you don't know. Your next step is to learn the basics of this language.

Comment: If only I had the time. :) I am not trying to get deep into the application or do major changes. I had just one line of code to add. But for that to be worth anything, I need the application to compile and run.

Comment: That line might be `vz := TVCLZ.Create(...)` where only you can possibly know what goes in place of `...`. And then you need to destroy the object too. In `FormDestroy` probably. With `vz.Free`. If you don't understand what I wrote then it would be unfair for you to continue with this question. You simply must have the pre-requisite knowledge. Why don't you spend the time gaining it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `vz: TVCLZ` is a component on a form. 
When you first open the form if you don't have the component (package) installed in the IDE it asks you if you want to remove the component (because the IDE doesn't know how to render/instantiate it at design-time). If you choose to remove it the code associated with that component remains.
So you remain with something similar to what you have. The form doesn't create the component at run-time (because it doesn't have it anymore) the `vz` member remains uninitialized.
So, you have to get the sources of the project with the component on the form and be careful not to delete it.

Or, you care create the instance yourself. At `FormCreate` just create it: `vz := TVCLZ.Create(Self);` before you use it. But keep in mind that all the properties set in design will be lost and you have to set them manually in code.

Comment: I don't think so. I think the IDE removes the reference too.

Comment: The IDE asks if you want to cancel, remove, etc. If you say "Cancel", the IDE will not modify anything, but it won't display the form either, because it can't. But if it removes, it removes from the .pas file too. I generally press "Cancel", find out which components are not installed, install them, and then close and reopen the form file(s) affected.

Comment: i think there's an _"ignore"_ option that behaves like what i have described above. Nevertheless it sure looks like it.

Comment: It looks like something in the good direction. I did have some messages about a package at first, though I don't think I did say yes to removing it. Anyway, after restarting everything (including the PC), it behaves better. I am still a bit worried at the lack of use of a Create function.

Comment: @PhilippeLignon if it is a visual component that is added to the form at design time then there is no need to manage its lifetime - the form itself will manage creation and destruction of the component without any additional code.  It sounds like you were simply either missing the package or had corrupted your .dfm file.

Comment: Thanks J... It looks like it was along those lines of a corrupt dfm file or something like that. Along with some wrong path and the fact that I have Delphi 7 that require a full restart of the PC everytime something was wrong, that made for a hard day. Once the initial setup was stable, I have been able to compile and run repeatedly and add the piece of code I required.